# Is there a formal proof for this theorem??

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is a theorem in the book Advanced Calculus by Wilfred Kaplan which states the following:

The differential formula :
$$
dz = \frac {\partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z} {\partial y}dy +........,
$$

which holds true when $z = f(x,y,.....)$ and $dx = \Delta x, dy = \Delta y,......,$ remains true when x,y,,....., and hence z are all functions of other independent variables and $dx,dy,.....,dz$ are all the corresponding differentials.

An example of use of this theorem is that one can do things like if
$ dz = A dx + B dy$, then $dx = \frac1Adz - \frac1Bdy$ and hence conclude that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac1A, \frac {\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{-1}{B}$ and so on.

It seemed to work intuitively by the chain rule and all but I cant help but wonder if there is a formal proof of this theorem.

Comment: This is formalized by the notion of a 1-form or covector in differential geometry. As you've written it, it really is nothing but a formal rule to remember the chain rule by.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in this WONDERFUL book:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=T968U5SsDY2jyAT-04HgCg&url=http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/fawaz/482/Books/Spivak_Calculus%2520on%2520manifolds.pdf&cd=15&ved=0CGAQFjAO&usg=AFQjCNGpFpdnK4fBuwwlNJswBhkCLeQfLA&sig2=sQ7lkEmWpAbA_k1krVabbg

You will find what you seek on PDF page 101. Page 89 of the actual book.